# MySQL : how to enable InnoDB engine in MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, innodb, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to enable InnoDB engine for MySQL 5.1.72, as I have to integrate it with Golden gate (to push DB changes to cache).  Could someone share any information?

Comment: show your my.cnf if linux or my.ini file if windows.

Comment: I copied the "/usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf" as "/etc/my.cnf" and updated this file for "InnoDB" to be used. I updated the below attribute as:
default-storage-engine = INNODB

Then ran "mysql> show engines;" and could see the InnoDB was set as default engine for my DB.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Zafar for quick response. Infact for GoldenGate, I also updated below in my.cnf:

default-storage-engine = INNODB
binlog_format = row
innodb_data_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql/data
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql/data

Comment: This is _NOT_ a duplicate of that VIM question!

Comment: True Rick. This has nothing to do with the VIM. How could this VIM link "delete word after or around cursor in VIM " be removed so other users are not misled?